# How to make a form behave like windows taskbar using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a taskbar using tabcontrols which works similarly to the Windows taskbar.
I want to make my own taskbar fixed on top of the windows.

It should not be movable, resizable, and it should be "docked" to the top.

Comment: But the Taskbar is movable and resizable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried to do this, but my first attempt would be the following:

- set form to be 'TopMost'
- set border to 'None'
- set Location: (0,0), Size(Screen.Width,H), where H is the Height you want your form to be
- set 'ShowInTaskBar' to false

Something you might consider: how will you handle multiple screens?

You'll likely want to add a context menu allowing you to exit the application, since it won't have the normal system buttons.  Also, you might consider what happens when the user presses ALT-F4: will your program close?  If not, you'll need to add some code in the FormClosing event handler to cancel closing.

Hope this sets you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

A long long time ago Jeffery Richter demonstrated how to do a true taskbar in a sample called AppBar (I've used it myself as a boiler plate), so here are some pages that may be of interest:

[http://www.google.com/search?q=Jeffrey+Richter+appbar+c#](http://www.google.com/search?q=Jeffrey+Richter+appbar+c%23&)